# Is it possible to share an Symfony2 installation (multiple websites [domains] on one server)

Tags: php, symfony, multiple-domains, vendors

I want to host multiple Symfony2 based websites under one root (server). Would it be possible to share the symfony own files? (vendors etc.). Does someone know a tutorial? Is it hard to manage? AFAIK a Symfony installation has about 600MB and I don't want to save this in a redundant manner ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I certainly looks possible. A few things to remember:

1. The `Symfony/vendors` folder contains all the Symfony related code. This can easily be shared between applications.
2. The `Symfony/app` folder contains application related files like the config and cache, and *shouldn't* be shared between applications.
3. The `Symfony/web` folder contains the public folder from which the application will be served, and *shouldn't* be shared.
4. The `Symfony/src` folder contains your bundles, and can be shared, depending on your needs

So at the very least, do the following:

1. Make copies of the `web` and `app` folders. Keep the copies in the `Symfony` folder. AFAIK, there's no easy way to have these folders in different locations.
2. In the new `app` folder, edit both `app.php` and `app_dev.php`. Replace all references to the `app` folder with the name of your new / second app folder.
3. Run `php newapp/console assets:install newapp` on your command line to install the bundled assets.

I'm sure you can also copy the `src` folder, although I haven't experimented with that. Reusing your bundles is probably a good idea in any way.

Comment: see [resolved - multiple websites on the same symfony2 base?](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=37166#p123723)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the framework ? If yes, you just can move the folder anywhere on your server (let's say '/usr/local/symfony') and from your sites, just load the autoloader from this directory.

Check out [this page of the documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony) for more info (in the "Installation Verification" part).

If you want to use the same application for all your websites, it has to be design for that...

Comment: yes, I am talking about the framework, but your link is about a previous version and AFAIK the new version is quite different (ordner structure and so on)..

Comment: Oops, didn't see that... Sorry ! I tried to look around, but there seem to be no documented way to do this yet.