# Using Symfony2 as a shared library across multiple sites

Tags: php, symfony, shared-libraries

I am new to Symfony2 but I am wanting to use it as my framework of choice for new sites that I develop.  I would like it so that I can use the framework across multiple sites without having to include it separately with each project.  This seems surprisingly difficult to achieve, or rather there doesn't seem to be any standard way of doing this that is documented.

So:

1. can I simply link all my projects to a single central point where the framework and common bundles are stored on the filesystem?  This doesn't seem to fit with the directory structure?
2. Can I generate the base app from this point using the console?

Ultimately is it just a case of symlinking the vendor directory or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several applications you could keep vendors separately. Vendors folder contains all the Symfony related code .

[How to change Symfony2 default structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280169/how-to-change-symfony2-default-structure)

[Is it possible to share an Symfony2 installation (multiple websites [domains] on one server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883628/is-it-possible-to-share-an-symfony2-installation-multiple-websites-domains-on)